# How to mute music in a mediaplayer created in a different activity?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have two activities, the one "Main.java" that initially loads I have a couple mediaPlayers that are created which control background music and a voice over.

The second activity is a "Settings.java" which is accessed through a settings cog icon, where I want to use On/Off toggle switches to allow the user to mute the two different mediaPlayer's.

The problem is, when I try to access the mediaPlayer name in the second activity, it can't find it since it's in a different activity.  I know this is a rather simple problem but this is my first app and first project in Java. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save a preference, say `'isPlayerOn'` in your `SettingsActivity` and check this preference in your `PlayerActivity`'s `onResume`. You can make `SettingsActivity extend PreferenceActivity` so you don't write extra code in there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  One approach I'm exploring now which seems to be working is creating a new "Globals" class, in which I created a public class globals and inside a public static mediaPlayer. This seems to allow me to access the mediaPlayer in both of the activities.  Is this advisable or your method most preferable?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this on your settings page

```
            public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean alertWarning = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();

            if (alertWarning) {
                // unMute();
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);

            } else {
                // mute();
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
            }
```